# Working on a legacy system that requires a full DMA controller (external DRQ/DACK mechanism) CPLD or FPGA vs Microcontroller

Tags: fpga, programmable-logic, dma

I'm working on a system that involves a legacy ASIC that requires a DMA controller. My current implementation is based on the STM32, but as you might know, the STM32 doesn't provide external DRQ/DACK mechanism for the DMA peripheral. I was wondering if a CPLD or FPGA can fill the gap and solve the problem for me. I have never used one in my designs, but referring to DMA controller IP cores available from Intel/ALTERA, I didn't see DRQ/DACK signals used in their implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: many microcontrollers are fast enough to emulate dma on old systems. Something like a Teensy 4.0 (imxrt1062) at 600MHz should suffice. As for CPLDs and fpgas, writing the HDL for a dma controller should be pretty simple - a state machine to sequence things and a counter of N bits for the address.

Comment: What speed do you need? If you connect an int handler to DRQ, how short can you get the handler required to save a word and toggle DACK? Is there an overlap between those two numbers?

Comment: @Kartman - 600 Mhz is way too much for the intended application. Don't forget that the ASIC used can't go beyond 5 Mb/s on its DMA bus so a microcontroller like the iMX is an overkill for such a product. In fact, the STM32F407 clocked @ 160 Mhz does the job very well. The only drawback is the DMA interface.

Comment: How can I forget when I’m not told?? If the stm32 is fast enough, where is your problem? Just write code to emulate the dma operation. You don’t even need a dma controller.

Comment: Well, I meant to say take into consideration the following. Now, as far as the problem is concerned, when I say the maximum data rate the ASIC can achieve on its DMA bus is 5 Mb/s, it doesn't mean that I was able to achieve that rate by bitbanging the ASIC on its parallel bus. I know that several scenarios might be achieved by playing with address lines, FMC, etc, however, that's not the end result sought. 

Aside from the details provided so far, I just wanted to know if I can implement a DMA controller similar in behavior and signaling (DREQ/DACK) to that of Intel's 8237 on FPGA or CPLD.

Comment: I just found the following:

https://www.microsemi.com/existing-parts/parts/151879

I guess this is exactly what I'm looking for, however, it's not available for free!

Comment: There seems to be a few implementations of the 8237 in verilog or vhdl. As previously mentioned writing one from scratch is reasonably straightforward - basically a counter and state machine. Other suggestions are the raspi pico that has a state machine for the port pins along with dma. Psoc5 that has some programmable logic and dma.

Comment: Of course, I don't mind going that route implementing my own DMA controller from scratch, but I don't have any working knowledge of VHDL or programmable logic devices. Like I said earlier, never used one before. I don't know if I can tackle this mission from first exposure to FPGAs. Can you provide link for any implementation of the 8237?